# FromEvent in Angular

Tags: angular, observable

I am new in Angular and trying to generate fromevent from button and just want to capture the event. I am not able to use fromevent. Can you please help and suggest that how to use fromevent with observables.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable,of } from 'rxjs'
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  NameCtrl:FormControl;
  button1=document.getElementById("btnClick");
  
  constructor(){
    this.NameCtrl=new FormControl();
    this.NameCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(value=>this.callMe(value))
       
  }

 
  callMe(str){
    console.log(str)
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Is the button within `app.component.html`? If so, why not use `(click)` binding on it?

Comment: Hi Gaurav, can you provide more information about your question? What is happening, and what are you expecting to happen? Do you specifically _need_ to use `fromEvent`? If not, there are better ways to detect clicks in Angular, and following an [Angular tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/user-input) might be helpful. If you do need to use `fromEvent`, can you be clearer about what you want to accomplish? Should the observable emit on every click?

Comment: Hello:I am trying to learn observable by button click. I have used below code for that. and trying to write something in console . If you see below code , I am successfully able to generate mousemove event and able to get the needed. But button click event is not getting generated.  (constructor(){
    this.NameCtrl=new FormControl();
    this.btn=new FormControl();
    this.NameCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(value=>this.callMe(value))

    this.btn1$=fromEvent(document.body,'mousemove');
    this.btn1$.subscribe(v=>this.MouseEvt(v));
       
  }
  callMe(str){
    console.log(str)
  }

Comment: I am getting below error ---------------Invalid event target
    at setupSubscription (fromEvent.js:50)
    at Observable._subscribe

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use `fromEvent` along with `defer` to subscribe Button click event.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { defer, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: `
    <button #testBtn>Click me</button>
  `
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('testBtn', { static: true }) testBtn: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;
  event$ = defer(() => fromEvent(this.testBtn.nativeElement, 'click')).pipe(
    map(() => new Date().toString()),
    tap(console.log)
  )
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.event$.subscribe();
  }
}
```

**Note:** I have used `defer` so it won't throw `Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined` error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using angular, and you're using native html selectors you need to have a very specific obscure reason for it. I've used it a couple of times, but it's a last resort solution.

So as suggested, use the `(click)` event binding in your template. Specifically

```
<button (click)="callMe()">
```

Also, while we're at it, please reserve capital casing for classes and not for class variables. `NameCtrl` ought to be `nameCtrl`.

Comment: ```fromEvent(button1, 'click')```; but I'm not to sure the getElementById will work at all; since it will run before the component is initialized (and thus the component most likely isn't there yet). You might want to use an ```@ViewChild``` and put the ```fromEvent``` in the ```ngOnInit```

Comment: I am sorry but I have not explicitly mentioned in my question. I would like to have observable from the fromevent and want to capture just a console long. I am trying to learn observable from button or any control click event. Basically I am not able to use fromevent in my code. I am always getting fromevent does not exists on type observable.

Comment: That's because it doesn't anymore. You have to directly import it, as in: 
```import {fromEvent} from 'rxjs';```
And no ```Observable.fromEvent``` but just ```fromEvent```

Comment: Thank you for your help! That helped but still not able to use that. I tried both ways. The one which is commented , I tried that as well.  export class AppComponent {
  NameCtrl:FormControl;
  btn=document.getElementById("btnClick");
  btn$;
    
  constructor(){
    this.NameCtrl=new FormControl();
   // this.btn=new FormControl();
    this.NameCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(value=>this.callMe(value))
    this.btn$=fromEvent(this.btn,'click');
    this.btn$.subscribe(v=>console.log('c'));